# Django: updating src on iframe without refreshing

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

i need to have a Django website, that has a homepage with an iframe.

There's a button, that (when clicked) changes the website displayed in the iframe by one chosen randomly from the database (a database of URLS).

Is there a way to do this with AJAX,jQuery or something like that? The problem is that, somehow i need to execute some view that randomly selects the url from my database. (It's forbidden to refresh or redirect, so i only need to change the iframe).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try writing a view that selects the URL from your database... And share the code and we can help wth any problems. It sounds pretty straight forward.

Comment: Writing the view is no problem at all. The issue is that i need to do this with AJAX, or something, because if a only use the view, i'll have to return some render, hence, redirect or refresh the page.

Comment: Okay, so you're mainly asking about the jquery/JavaScript/AJAX. Thanks for the clarification. Yes, that is fairly straightforward and can absolutely be done via AJAX. Lalo's answer is a good step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to show us more details, view, models some html and javascript that you already have. However, I'll make a simple way to do it.

```
#models.py

Class Page(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()

#views.py

def random_page_view(request):
    response_data = {}
    page = Page.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    response_data['page_url'] = page.url
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")

#random_page.html

<!-- I guess you have something like -->
<iframe id='random-page' src='some url'></iframe>
<button id='new-page-button'>Click me!</button>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#new-page-button').on('click', function(event){
        $.get( "{% url 'get_random_url' %}", function( data ) {
           $( "#random-page" ).attr('src', data.page_url);
        });
    });
  })
</script>
```

**NOTE:** Maybe you dont have to use order_by('?'), it's slow. (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by))

**NOTE 2:** If you dont have any Page, it's gonna fail :)

Comment: I've omitted the view that renders `random_page.html`, and all `urls.py files`

Comment: ONe doubt, in the funcion you use, when you typed $.get("{% url 'get_random_url' %}, function (data)...., you meant instead of get_random_url, random_page_view (the view you defined earlier)?

Comment: `'get_random_url'` is a named url (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) ), that must use the `random_page_view` function (or view)